# Optimal Database to be used for metro apps?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro, local-storage, windows-runtime

I am new to windows 8 metro apps development and i need your help  in figuring out my doubt about the database support to metro applications ?

i am developing a application which requires reasonably huge amount of data to be stored in its database , it would require many tables and relation between them , with help of this i can fetch the data from database and show it to user , and perform the required operations on it and sync the data when internet connection is there.

Please let me know which is the optimal database for metro applications for me to use in my app.

As per my knowledge these are the present alternatives for database support for metro applications (i might be wrong , please correct me if i am wrong):-

1)IndexedDB  2)SQLite   3)WinRT File Based Database  4)Siaqodb     5)Devart LinqConnect

Thanks in advance.

Your answer might clear doubts of  many developers like me  about database support , Please feel free to answer it.

Comment: Do you want a local database, or one on a server?  When you say 'reasonably huge', is that too much for local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/07/sqlite-metro-winmobile

http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx

SQLite on WinRT is probably your best bet...

Chad

Answer (score 1):

IMO you forgot about one more solution. This solution probably will be best for you. Use external DB and webservice/webapi to communicate with it.
In my project I'm using Azure SQL. I communicate my Metro app with it by webapi that is published in cloud.