# Metro Apps - SQLite vs Indexed Db

Tags: javascript, windows-8, sqlite, microsoft-metro, indexeddb

I am about to start working on a metro app using JavaScript/HTML which will store data locally, when no internet connection is there and also planning to port the same on other platform's later.

What would be the right choice for database -
SQLite or Indexed db ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707891/optimal-database-to-be-used-for-metro-apps

Comment: @Xyroid isn't SQLite support is deprecated ?

Comment: what type of data access do you need?  if relational is important, you'd perhaps trend to SQLite.  IndexedDB though as 'built-in' to HTML5 may be easier - fewer moving parts.

Comment: @JimO'Neil i will be maintaining meta data about files.

Comment: @Xyroid http://www.nitrix-reloaded.com/2012/12/18/html5-bye-bye-websqlsqlite-welcome-indexeddb/
http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Comment: The link you gave me is for Web App developer not for Windows 8 Developer, though I am C#/XAML developer so I am using SQLite not idea about HTML/WinJS

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say that `IndexedDB` is a much better option than SQLite for Windows 8 applications because:

- It's built into the browser, so the code you're writing has skill portability to web applications
- There are several good libraries out there to simplify working with it ([pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com), [db.js](https://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js), [jQuery IndexedDB](https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb), and many more)
- The API is designed to work with JavaScript objects, particularly when it comes to querying, unlike SQLite which you (generally speaking) will have to create SQL statements as strings